# How to make an argument accept only my functions?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a function which takes in a Composable function as an argument

```kotlin
fun myFunction(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
}
```

I want to control the different types of composables, a user can pass is as a parameter. More precisely, I only want the user to pass one of the following 3 functions as an argument.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun fun1() {}

@Composable
fun fun2() {}

@Composable
fun fun3() {}
```

How can I enforce this?

Comment: If your function accepts only 3 predefined argument variants, why it's argument is not `enum` for example? if you don't want to accept custom logic as argument, higher-order function is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution i can think of would be to use a functional interface in order for the `content` parameter to be constrained by it.

So you would define a functional interface for you three functions :

```
fun interface ConstrainedContent {
    @Composable
    operator fun invoke()
}
```

Then you implement the interface for each of the content functions :

```
val function1 = object: ConstrainedContent {
    @Composable
    override fun invoke() {
        Text("My Content 1")
    }
}
```

Here I'm explicitly overriding the invoke method and not converting it as a lambda as there seems to be a type inference problem with the composable.

Then in your `myFunction`

```
@Composable
fun myFunction(content: ConstrainedContent) {
    content()
}
```

So this would be a way to do it and only your implementations of the ConstrainedContent could be used in `myFunction` but i'm not sure if there are some downside to this solution on the composition.